# Find exact numbers from a string separated by commas in Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a column (Example) that contains one or multiple numbers ranging from 1 to 14. If there are multiple numbers it will be separated by a comma, for example: 1, 3, 6.

I want to write a condition in *Power Query* that flags the exact number I specify. In the image below, I wanted to find the number 1 only but 11 was also flagged in the (Filter) column.

[image]

Here is the query I wrote `= if Text.Contains([Example],"1,") or [Example]="1" then "Yes" else "No"`

[image]

Please let me know how to achieve this by finding the exact number in the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In powerquery, add column .. custom column .. with formula

Method1: Finds if "1" exists.  Not 1 inside of another number, 1 by itself

```
= Text.Contains(" "&Text.From([Example])&", "," 1,")
```

or

```
= List.Contains(List.Transform(try Text.Split([Example],", ") otherwise {[Example]}, each Text.From(_)),"1")
```

Method2: Finds if "1" exists, even if inside another item like 312

```
= Text.Contains(Text.From([Example]),"1")
```

[image]